# C++ -> Assertion failure Stack

Tags: c++, stack, assertion

I am working on getting a stack of strings (the String ADT I made myself,) for my CS class but I am caught on one part of it, and can not figure out what is wrong. When I compile the code using a Makefile, I get the error: *test_default_ctor: ./stack.hpp:53: T stack::pop() [T = String]: Assertion `TOS!=0' failed.*

Where my test is not running because of the pop() function that I have declared in my header file. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
#ifndef STACK_HPP
#define STACK_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <new>

#include "string/string.hpp"

template <typename T>
class node{
public:
    node(): next(0), data(){};
    node(const T& x): next(0), data(x){};

    node<T> *next;
    T data;
    // EXAM QUESTION: This class is going to be used by another class so all needs to be accessable
    // Including node p and node v.
};

template <typename T>
class stack{
public:
    stack(): TOS(0){};
    ~stack();
    stack(const stack<T>&);
    void swap(stack<T>&);
    stack<T>& operator=(stack<T> rhs){swap(rhs); return *this;};
    bool operator==(const stack<T>&) const;
    bool operator!=(const stack<T>& rhs) const {return !(*this == rhs);};
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const stack<T>&);
    bool isEmpty()const{return TOS == 0;};
    bool isFull(void)const;
    T pop(void);
    void push(const T&);
    int slength()const{String nuevo; return nuevo.length();};
private:
    node<T> *TOS;
};

template <typename T>
T stack<T>::pop(){
    assert(TOS!=0);
    node<T> *temp=TOS;
    T result=TOS -> data;
    TOS=TOS -> next;
    int len=slength();
    --len;
    delete temp;
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
bool stack<T>::operator==(const stack<T>& rhs) const{
    stack<T> left = *this;
    stack<T> right = rhs;

    if(slength() != rhs.slength())
            return false;   
    if(left.pop() != right.pop())
            return false;     
    else                 
            return true;
}
```

and here is my test:

```
#include "stack.hpp"
#include "string/string.hpp"

#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    {
            stack<String> test;
            assert(test == stack<String>());
            assert(test.slength()==0);
    }


    std::cout<<"Done testing default constructor!"<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I know this is happening because the top of stack (TOS) is 0, but I don't know why the assertion will not let it go through even though the pop function isn't being called at all in my test. ANyone able to provide any help?

Comment: I'm guessing you're not showing all of the code and `pop` is being called somewhere.

Comment: Taking a step back after what you said, I feel like it might be an issue with my equal operator, so I edited that one in there, I think that may be the issue.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you posted your `operator==` code, it's obvious what is going on.  That operator is calling `pop` on an empty stack.  You have to rewrite your `operator==` function so it doesn't use `pop`.  `pop` modifies the stack do you don't want to use it.  You should loop through each node of your stacks and compare them for equality.

Also, I would eliminate the two lines I highlight below.  That are making  **copies** of your stacks which, in general, you don't want to do if it's not needed.  Also, since your class contains pointers, you should write an `operator=` correctly.  Since the code is using the compiler generated default `operator=` it is not correct.

```
template <typename T>
bool stack<T>::operator==(const stack<T>& rhs) const{
    stack<T> left = *this;  // remove this
    stack<T> right = rhs;   // remove this

    if(slength() != rhs.slength())
            return false;   
    if(left.pop() != right.pop())
            return false;     
    else                 
            return true;
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I completely overlooked those when I was checking it over. So you're saying my operator= is not correct on top of the pop? I have it up there, but this is the one I have: stack<T>& operator=(stack<T> rhs){swap(rhs); return *this;};

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your `operator=`.  It looks correct, assuming your `swap` and `copy constructor` are implemented correctly.